# Defining grid.arrange() so the third plot is in the middle?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm making three plots with ggplot2. I want to put them onto the same space. To put them into the same space I am using grid.arrange(), with 2 columns and 2 rows. Instead of having the third figure in position (2,1) be on the left, is there a way for me to center it in the middle of the space? Open to suggestions beyond grid.arrange() as well.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()

P2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()

P3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec)) +
  geom_histogram()

grid.arrange(P1, P2, P3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea about gridExtra, but since you said alternatives are OK, it's really straightforward with patchwork :)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()

P2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()

P3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec)) +
  geom_histogram()

(P1 + P2) / P3
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know that was possible! Thank you!

Comment: No worries, patchwork is basically magic! Definitely check out the materials, there are some really useful tools

Comment: I checked out the website: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/. This is so much more straightforward and I appreciate the flexibility it offers. I'll definitely be using this from now on. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer for anyone interested in using `grid.arrange()`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

P1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram()

P2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_histogram()

P3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec)) +
  geom_histogram()


grid.arrange(P1, P2, P3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)


#This will get you 2 plots on top and 1 plot in the middle at the bottom
grid.arrange(P1, P2, P3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, layout_matrix= rbind(c(1,2), 3))

#This will get you 1 plot in the middle at top and 2 plots at the bottom
grid.arrange(P1, P2, P3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, layout_matrix= rbind(c(1,1),c(2,3)))
```

Comment: and to center in the middle can use `layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,1, 2,2), c(NA, 3, 3, NA))`